# WCF Property wont set in response

Tags: c#, wcf, windows

i have a problem with WCF service.. i am using service reference in windows app project. In Reply to one of my wcf methods there is a class which has a propety ID int (datacontract) it always comes 0. When i try from code it works. but when i actually installl the wcf service and try it comes 0. any idea guys ? some settings with proxy? anything at all?

```
[DataMember(Order = 1)]
public int ID { get; set; }

[DataMember(Order = 2)]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

now quantiy is populated, but ID is always 0. I chekcd the database calls, ID and quantiyt is returned. also mapping are all correct. From code i get both values but when i install setup this ID field never retuned

Comment: What do you mean `installl the wcf service`? Is it delpoyed on IIS?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Yes, deployed on IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to multilingual application. This code worked fine for English, but in other language login it failed.
Reason being, In request parameter dates were passed, and for login other than english, date comparison used to fail.